# Using png files from a folder for flask app

Tags: python, html, jinja2

pardon me I am a newbie, I am building a flask app with the following structure

```
.
├── routes.py
├── templates
│   ├── index.html
│   └── layout.html
└── img
    ├── 1.png
    └── 2.png
    └── 3.png and so on
```

I am trying to render all the images from the img folder to index.html in a list and i want to use jinja template to do that.the number of images in the img folder is not specified and i need all the images in my index.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure that I understand you correctly. It sound like you only want to get a list off all the images in a folder.

```py
from glob import iglob
from os.path import basename

@app.route(...)
def list_images():
    pngs = iglog('img/*.png')                  # An iterator of 'img/1.png', 'img/2.png', ...
    pngs = (basename(png) for png in pngs)     # Strip the directory name
    return render_template('list_images.html', # A normal jinga template
                           pngs=pngs)          # That gets the iterator of names as argument
```

```
<table>
{% for png in pngs %}           {# Just iterate over the names #}
    <tr><td>{{ png }}</td></td>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```